# Unity Broken text PPtr when saving asset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialog, assets, scriptable-object

I recently upgraded my version of Unity 2021.1 and now when I call AssetDatabase.SaveAssets(), I get the error

```
[Worker0] Broken text PPtr in file(Assets/Game/Dialogue/Dialogue.asset). Local file identifier (1528208011795455128) doesn't exist!
```

I never had this error in the previous version of Unity. Everything still works but this error does popup in the console on the AseetDatabase.SaveAssets() call. It only occurs when I create a new node for my dialog system.

I added a button to my dialog editor than when clicked it calls AssetDatabase.SaveAssets() and this doesn't throw the error but I don't want this. I want to save whenever I add a new node.

```
public DialogueNode CreateNode(DialogueNode parent, Vector2 position)
{
    var newNode = MakeNode(parent, position);
    
    Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(newNode, "Create Dialogue Node");
    Undo.RecordObject(this, "Add Dialogue Node");
    
    AddNode(newNode);
    
    return newNode;
}

private DialogueNode MakeNode(DialogueNode parent, Vector2 position)
{
    DialogueNode newNode = CreateInstance<DialogueNode>();
    newNode.name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    newNode.SetSize(140, 40);
    if (parent != null)
    {
        parent.AddChild(newNode.name);
        newNode.Parent = parent;
        newNode.IsPlayerSpeaking = !parent.IsPlayerSpeaking;
    
        newNode.SetPosition(parent.Rect.position + newNodeOffset, Grid.GridSnapSize);
    
        if (parent.Children.Count > 1)
            parent.SetSize(new Rect(parent.Rect.x, parent.Rect.y, 150, 40));
    }
    else
    {
        newNode.SetPosition(position, Grid.GridSnapSize);
    }
    
    return newNode;
}

private void AddNode(DialogueNode newNode)
{
    newNode.Text = "";
    nodes.Add(newNode);
    OnValidate();
    Save();
}

private void Save() => AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();

public void CreateNew()
{
    if (nameForNew == "")
        return;

    var newItem = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>();
    newItem.name = "New " + typeof(T); //May not need

    if (path == "")
     path = "Assets/";

     AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(newItem, path + "\\" + nameForNew + ".asset");
     AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();

     nameForNew = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to rather explicitly use [`AssetDatabase.CreateAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.CreateAsset.html) for your new created asset.

- Makes more sense than saving **all** assets across the entire project
- your new asset doesn't have any save path yet so where would you expect unity to save it persistently?

You basically are creating and storing only a "virtual" instance of a ScriptableObjec without the according persistent asset ...

So I think what the error means is you are trying to save (= serialize) your base/parent node including the according child node references.

However, since you never create the actual assets these references can not be serialized and are valid only temporary.

Comment: I do use AssetDatabase.CreateAsset when I create the actual dialog. Its the creation of the nodes that is the issue. I added some code above to show how I create the asset.

Comment: I moved the AssetDatabase.SaveAssets()to my OnSelectionChanged for my dialog editor and the error doesn't appear anymore but the issue is it only saves when I select a different dialog. I would like it to save every time I add a new node.

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error attempts and hours of debugging I was able to solve it.

```
EditorApplication.delayCall += AssetDatabase.SaveAssets;
```

Now whenever I call AssetDatabase.SaveAssets() from the Save() function, I no longer get these errors. It appears I have to wait for the inspector to be updated.  With this method, the call to AssetDatabase.SaveAssets() will be delayed until the inspector has been refreshed.